# POST end point in Azure function

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am creating an azure functional app but facing issue with the POST method. I am getting json as input for this.

main.py

```
import azure.functions as func
from .CreateEmployee import Employee

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if req.method == "POST":
       data = req.get_json()
       response, status_code = Employee().post()
       return func.HttpResponse(response, status_code)
```

CreateEmployee.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

Class Employee(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            parser = reqparser.RequestParser()
            parser.add_argument('EmpId', type=int)
            parser.add_argument('Dept', type=int)
        
            args = parser.parse_args()
        
            cursor = get_db() #connection from another .py file
            .
            .
            .
            return str("Employee Added Successfully"),201
        except:
            return str("Bad gateway"),502
```

Here I am getting error at "args = parser.parse_args()".
Error:
"RuntimeError : Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
needed an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing
for information about how to avoid this problem."

Any help on this?

Thanks,
Sud

Comment: Can you share the error text? It may also be helpful to know what the json you are sending looks like.

Comment: I have added the error code as well

Comment: Where is the `ProjectList`?

Comment: I have updated the class name to Employee. It's misspelled.